# pyuic4 generates wrong layout?

Tags: layout, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer, pyuic

pyuic4 seems to generate a wrong layout based on a .ui file from Qt Designer. The UI file is here:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>348</width>
    <height>267</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
   <item>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item alignment="Qt::AlignTop">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>16777215</width>
         <height>25</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:14pt;&quot;&gt;Some Text&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item alignment="Qt::AlignTop">
      <widget class="Line" name="line_2">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item alignment="Qt::AlignBottom">
      <widget class="Line" name="line">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <item alignment="Qt::AlignBottom">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_customize">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Customize</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item alignment="Qt::AlignBottom">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_done">
         <property name="text">
          <string>OK</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

In this layout, I'm trying to align a pair of buttons with the bottom of the dialog window and some text with the top. Running `pyuic4 test.ui --preview` shows all objects aligned to the center horizontally, instead of to the top and bottom (and displaying this dialog from the actual python program shows the same results). By comparison, `pyuic5 test.ui --preview` seems to be more along the lines of what I wanted to get.

If it helps, my version of pyuic4 is 4.11.4 and I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong? Or is there perhaps a newer pyuic4 out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was bug in pyuic that affected the handling of alignment in layouts. This was fixed in PyQt-5.5, which was released on the 17th July 2015. However, PyQt-4.11.4 (which is the current version) was released on the 11th June 2015 - so the fix has not been included, yet. The current development snapshot for PyQt-4.12 does includes the fix, though.

But I don't think this will really fix the issue you have. What you need to do instead is use expanding spacers. Here's how to do this using your example ui file:

1. Click on the horizontal button layout, and then click Break Layout (this will remove all the current layouts).
2. Ctrl+click the two buttons, and then click Layout Horizontally.
3. Click on the Dialog, and then click Layout Vertically.
4. Drag and drop a Vertical Spacer between the two Line widgets

Giving you this:

[image: screenshot]

If you want to have some other widgets in the central area, you may need to add expanding vertical spacers above and/or below them to get the same results. Then again, if you put something like a text-box or list-widget in there, it should automatically expand to fill the available space - in which case, there wouldn't be any need for any spacers (or layout alignments).

Comment: +one for informing about bug and explaining beyond original example